# What would be an "or otherwise" method to solve this question?

Tags: probability

A game is played where a blue die (with faces $4,6,8,9,10$ and $12$)and a pink die (with faces $2,3,5,7,11$ and $13$) are thrown once. The player wins if the number on the pink die is higher than the blue die.

The question guides me to draw a table of possible outcomes *or otherwise*. The table was easy enough (and answer of $\frac{7}{18}$) but what would the otherwise method refer to? I can't think of any combinatoric argument to solve the question. Probably a method that avoids cases would be the best but it seems as if that is unavoidable in this case.

So I know for sure that the two numbers must be distinct and if the pink dies lands on $2$ or $3$ it is impossible to win. How do I get an expression in $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ from here?

Comment: It would help to get the exact text of the question, as this is a grammar issue more than a math issue. Without the exact text, I’d assume that “or otherwise” mean list all the cases, where the player wins and where the player  loses (the otherwise cases.)

Comment: Thank you for showing some of your work and your answer.  With that I imagine I have the correct scenario in mind. See my Answer with two 'methods' both agreeing with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Approximation by simulation.** In R, I simulated 10 million rolls of the blue and pink die.
The pink die has the larger number in very nearly $7/18$
of the 10 million. With $10^7$ iterations, one can expect
three-place accuracy. The simulation illustrates that
your answer is correct.

```
set.seed(306)
blu = c(4,6,8,9,10,12)
pnk = c(2,3,5,7,11,13)
x = sample(blu, 10^7, rep=T)
y = sample(pnk, 10^7, rep=T)
mean(y > x)
[1] 0.3890144  # approx P(Y > X) = 7/18
7/18
[1] 0.3888889  

hdr = "ECDF Plots: Blue (Mostly) Dominates Pink"
plot(ecdf(x), col="blue", main=hdr)
 lines(ecdf(y), col="pink", lwd=3, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

**An alternative probabilistic solution.** For each possible pink
number (probability $1/6)$ determine what fraction of blue numbers
it can beat. Each term is a probability $(1/6)$ multiplied by a conditional probability. [Essentially, you already mentioned two of the six terms.]

```
(1/6)*(0 + 0 + (1/6) + (2/6) + (5/6) + 1)
[1] 0.3888889
```